# Symfony - manually add phpxmlrpc to vendor

Tags: php, symfony, xml-rpc, vendor

I need to use XML-RPC on my project. I have found a library phpxmlrpc (http://phpxmlrpc.sourceforge.net/) and I need to add it to vendor. I have copied the files in vendor folder (/vendor/phpxmlrpc/) and I need to see the xmlrpc_client class in my Controller. But I am not able to manage how to edit autoload.php to see the class, after a few attemps I am still getting "Attempted to load class "xmlrpc_client" from the global namespace.
Did you forget a "use" statement?" so I am pretty sure that there is some mess in my structure. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload`

Answer (score 1):

You must use a composer install tools for integrate 3third party code in your project a lot of possible time.

For XML-RPC you have this bundle : [Symfony-rpc-bundle](https://github.com/skolodyazhnyy/symfony-rpc-bundle)

When you install with composer install your bundle a lot of tricks run in your project symfony. Don't forget to add this bundle in your AppKernel.php file.

With this your code for XML-RPC is more upkeeping and stable.

Comment: I am trying to use all bundles with composer as much as possible, this is first situation for me - your suggested bundle did not work for me and this phpxmlrpc did.. So that's why I am trying to integrate it in Symfony, but without any success so far :/

Answer (score 0):

A bit late with the answer, I fear, but phpxmlrpc can now be installed using Composer as you would do with any other package.

When checking out info about that library, just make sure that you look up the latest version on GitHub and not any more on SourceForge.

Comment: I have used composer to install phpxmlrpc/phpxmlrpc - all looks fine.  I have autoloading enabled as I use it with other composer installed libraries.  However when I try to use create a new xmlrpc_client it can't find the class.

Comment: That is because you should not use the legacy classes such as xmlrpc_client. You should use new classes such as XmlRpc\Client instead. The legacy classes are kept around only for compatibility with old code.

Comment: Yes - good to know.  I now have a working test system, using both Client and Server classes.  So far so good.